# How can I get Xcode to find the <Everyplay/Everyplay.h> header?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, everyplay

When using the Everyplay SDK, Xcode properly recognizes the .framework and .bundle from the beginning, without me having to point to the directory manually, but the "Headers" file in the .framework doesn't seem to parse into anything.

It's plaintext-readable as Versions/Current/Headers, but that doesn't seem to actually let Xcode know how to get to the header files found in that directory. As a result, EveryplayUnity.h fails at #import , since it can't find that header.

How can I get Xcode to find this header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually the result from unzipping the SDK on Windows environment, which doesn't support typical symbolic links used by Mac OS X/Unix environments.

On multi-platform development environments, it's usually best to extract the SDK on a Mac and use the tools there (git, svn, ..) to add it to your version control system of choice.